# Jquery .datepicker() - on a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to create a dynamic table with each row containing two date fields. I am using Jquery datepicker. For some reason only the first row is showing in the date picker calendar. Other dynamically created fields are not showing the calendar. I should mention that the first row is by default in place when this page is loaded. Only from the second line it's dynamically created. All solutions say I should reinitialize the .datepicker(). I did and it's not working. I tried changing names and Ids still no solution. Is there something I am missing here. Below is the code used for this purpose.

Yes I know there are several questions related to this here in this site. But some how I couldn't find a solution to this as they aren't working for me.

Javascript:

```
$("#addurl").click(function(){
var idValue = "input[id='breachCount']";
var counter = $(idValue).val();
var trValue = $("#rowPH"+counter).html();
var countNew = parseInt(counter)+1;
$(idValue).val(countNew);
var newFile = "<tr id='rowPH"+countNew+"'>"+trValue+"</tr>";
$(newFile).insertBefore("#addLink");
var nameTemp, actNm;
var dcounter=0;
$('#rowPH'+countNew+' input').each(function(){
    nameTemp = $(this).attr("name");
    if(nameTemp){
        actNm = nameTemp.substring(nameTemp.indexOf("."));
  $(this).attr("name","breachList["+countNew+"]"+actNm+countNew);
    }
    });
$('.datepicker').each(function(i) {
            this.id = 'datepicker' + i;
    }).datepicker();                
});
```

Html:

```
<table>.....
<tr id="rowPH0">
<td>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</td>
<td>
<input class="text_box_2 div_center" type="text" value="" name="breachList[0].breachText">
</td>
<td>
<input id="datepicker0" class="datepicker date_txt hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="breachList[0].activationDt"><img class="calendar" src="assets/images/calendar_icon.png">
</td>
<td>
   <input id="datepicker1" class="datepicker date_txt hasDatepicker" type="text" value=""  name="breachList[0].deactivationDt">
   <input type="checkbox" name="breachList[0].deactiveNa" checked="checked">
</td>
<td>
   <input class="text_box_2" type="text" value="" name="breachList[0].note">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr id="rowPH1">
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
</td>
<td>
    <input class="text_box_2 div_center" type="text" value="" name="breachList[1].breachText1">
</td>
<td>
  <input id="datepicker2" class="datepicker date_txt hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="breachList[1].activationDt1">
    <img class="calendar" src="assets/images/calendar_icon.png">
</td>
<td>
     <input id="datepicker3" class="datepicker date_txt hasDatepicker" type="text" value="" name="breachList[1].deactivationDt1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="breachList[1].deactiveNa1" checked="checked">
</td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr id="addLink">
    <td colspan="5" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addurl">+ Add another row</a>
     <input type="hidden" id="breachCount" value="${fn:length(auditStandardBreachsForm.breachList)-1}"/>
</td></tr>
...</table>
```

Comment: Do you have some CSS that may be throwing off the layout?

Comment: I don't think so Brian. I am currently using "jquery-ui-custom.css" for the datepicker and no other css used in the page is overriding them.Then again the datepicker is working for the first row and in other places where i have used them separately. Its seems to be a problem initializing the datepicker dynamically. i.e calling .datepicker() . It doesn't seem to initialize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessary to assign unique ids to each field. Datepicker can identify each uniquely. Try putting following code in your js.

```
$('.datepicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

I've used it for multiple fields.

****Update****

I read your js code and it's messed up. All you want to do is (from what you've stated) is when user clicks on **Add Another Link** , you want to add a new row in table and want them to be able to work with jQuery datepicker. Right?

The reason above code is not working is, in this case, text fields are being added dynamically . While `datepciker` gets initialized on `onDocumentReady`. So datepicker can not attach itself to these newly created form fields. A solution is to attach datepicker while creating new fields itself.

Here's a working model I prepared for what you want to achieve. See demo on http://jsfiddle.net/phazorrise/bRE6q/

Comment: I have tried it . it is not working ... Is there any loop hole int he code other than that.

Comment: @Har I've updated my answer and given a demo too. See if it helps you.

Comment: I should say brilliant and thankyou for the line     `$(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();` . I cannot accept my JS is messed up one :). Its the kind of necessasity that requires what you call it as mess. I used same JS and you line I mentioned. It works like a charm. I should also mention is this datepicker also needs a different id in some scenerios like I have. If the id aren't the same then the date is wherever I selected is loading only in one input field not on the appropriate element. Thanks again for all your time. Again... Brilliant.I will give you a tick.

Comment: @Har Datepicker plugin automatically assign unqiue ids. If you inspect textfields you'll find unique ids are already set by using timestamp.

Comment: hmm yes I have seen that but in my case I am cloning the html which had the timestamp id datepicjker element. So all the rows will have the same id. Isnt it? Adn that was what happening..

Answer (score 1):

here is my updated code

Javascript
Modified at the bottom of the above javascript

```
var nameTemp, actNm;
$('#rowPH'+countNew+' input').each(function(){
    nameTemp = $(this).attr("name");
    if(nameTemp){
      actNm = nameTemp.substring(nameTemp.indexOf("."));
      $(this).attr("name","breachList["+countNew+"]"+actNm);
      $(this).attr("id","breachList["+countNew+"]"+actNm+countNew); //added 
    }
});
$('.datepicker').each(function(i) {
    $(this).removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker(); //changed ref: phazor comment
 });
```